# 2D game with angled top-down camera perspective

Tags: 2d, camera, perspective, third-person-view

I want to create a game similar to binding of isaac, a slightly angled top-down 2D game. In binding of isaac, the character moves and shoots along a 4-way path, so when he is shooting towards East, the character is facing East, same for North, West and South. In my game I need to shoot at any given angle, so it will look pretty bad if the character is facing East but the bullet is going North-East, I considered creating 8 or even 16 sprites with the character facing at different at different angles. But I don't know if it will look good either.

I would like to know if anyone encountered this problem and if there is any solution beside switching to 3D, because is not a solution at this moment.

[image: Binding of isaac]

In this image(Binding of Isaac) it may look like the player shoots at any given angle but it's not, he moved to the left immediately ofter shooting.

Comment: So... what exactly is the problem you are having? Please note that questions simply asking our opinion ("do you think this will look good?") aren't considered on-topic here.

Comment: It is my first game and I would like to know if 8 sprites will be enough to get a good look and feel

Comment: That's entirely up to opinion. Try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

Simply choose the facing for the character that is closest to the angle of the shot. 8 sets of sprites would be nice for that, but I imagine just the 4 cardinal directions would look fine too. Character faces North for any shots between NW to NE, character faces East for any shots between NE to SE, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I will go with 8 sprites and see what happens.